# C++14 Lambda - Conditionally Capture by Reference or Value

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

Is it possible to conditionally choose the capture method of a lambda based on compile time information?  For example...

```
auto monad = [](auto && captive) {
    return [(?)captive = std::forward<decltype(captive)>(captive)](auto && a) {
        return 1;
    };
};
```

I want capture by reference if `decltype(captive)` is a `std::reference_wrapper`, and everything else captured by value.

Comment: Isn't the point of `reference_wrapper` that it's like a reference, except it can be passed around by value without a problem? Why then is *that* type the type you want to capture by reference? What's wrong with just capturing everything by value?

Comment: @hvd I don't want to capture `reference_wrapper` by reference, I want to capture the reference it holds by reference.  Reference wrapper does it's best to be a like a reference, but since the call operator (aka, "." operator) cannot be overloaded, it fails pretty miserably at the end of the day.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. That makes more sense. So you don't want to capture `captive` by reference if it's a `reference_wrapper`, you want to capture `captive.get()` by reference, right?

Comment: @hvd, yeah, exactly.  I should edit the question since I didn't make that very clear

Comment: @pat that is known as "operator-dot", when I read "the call operator" I thought you meant the function call operator, `operator()`

Comment: @JonathanWakely My bad, I'll change it.

Comment: @hvd It wouldn't be stored by reference if lambdas were capable of doing what I was asking about.  The 123 would be captured by value in the lambda returned by monad(), since it was not passed in a std::reference_wrapper.

Comment: @pat Yep, you're right, that would be me seriously misreading what you're trying to do. :)

Answer (score 4):

Lambda capture type cannot be controlled by template-dependent names.

However, you could achieve the desired effect by delegating creating the inner lambda to an overloaded function:

```
template<class T>
auto make_monad(T&& arg) {
    return [captive = std::forward<T>(arg)](auto&& a) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " " << a << '\n';
        return 1;
    };
}

template<class T>
auto make_monad(std::reference_wrapper<T> arg) {
    return [&captive = static_cast<T&>(arg)](auto&& a) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " " << a << '\n';
        return 1;
    };
}

int main() {
    auto monad = [](auto&& captive) {
        return make_monad(std::forward<decltype(captive)>(captive));
    };

    int n = 1;
    monad(1)(1);
    monad(n)(2);
    monad(std::ref(n))(3);
}
```

Outputs:

```
make_monad(T&&)::<lambda(auto:1&&)> [with auto:1 = int; T = int] 1
make_monad(T&&)::<lambda(auto:1&&)> [with auto:1 = int; T = int&] 2
make_monad(std::reference_wrapper<_Tp>)::<lambda(auto:2&&)> [with auto:2 = int; T = int] 3
```

---

> I don't want to capture reference_wrapper by reference, I want to capture the reference it holds by reference. Reference wrapper does it's best to be a like a reference, but since the call operator (aka, "." operator) cannot be overloaded, it fails pretty miserably at the end of the day.

In this case you do not need to change the capture type for `std::reference_wrapper<T>`. Instead, you may like to capture it by value like any other type of argument and at the usage site unwrap the argument first:

```
template<class T> T& unwrap(T& t) { return t; }
template<class T> T& unwrap(std::reference_wrapper<T> t) { return t; }

auto monad = [](auto && captive) {
    return [captive](auto && a) {            // <--- Capture by value.
        auto& captive_ref = unwrap(captive); // <--- Unwrap before usage.
        return 1;
    };
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I know there are a bunch of old school ways of doing it, I was just hoping C++14 would allow for some brevity in the solution.

Comment: @Casey Most likely, the original question, though, wanted to capture the wrapper by reference.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't answer your question but your comment, How to use `operator .`:

You may add those two overloads:

```
template <typename T>
T& get_reference_object(T&& t) { return t; }

template <typename T>
T& get_reference_object(std::reference_wrapper<T> t) { return t.get(); }
```

and then you may use `get_reference_object(arg).foo` inside your lambda:

```
auto monad = [](auto && captive) {
    return [captive = captive](auto&& a) { return get_reference_object(captive).foo(a); };
};
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f95e3833fa13009).